# Python C Extension Keyword arguments

Tags: python, c, python-c-extension

**Description of problem:**

When I call method defined like this:

```
static PyMethodDef Parser_methods[] = {
    {"read", (PyCFunction)Parser_read, METH_KEYWORDS, "read from input source"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL} 
};

static PyObject *
Parser_read(Parser * const self, PyObject * unused0, PyObject * unused1)
{
...
}
```

I got:

```
SystemError: Bad call flags in PyCFunction_Call. METH_OLDARGS is no longer supported!
```

The code works fine on Python2, but crashes on Python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be this bug...

http://bugs.python.org/issue11587

Which means it's a python version issue.  One fix seems to be to use `METH_KEYWORDS | METH_VARARGS`.

Comment: just ran in the same problem. I'm not sure, how or where to set METH_KEYWORDS | METH_VARARGS and would highly appreciate any clarification.

Comment: thanks! this fixed error `SystemError: rsa_generate() method: bad call flags` in [pycryptopp](https://github.com/tahoe-lafs/pycryptopp/pull/47) with python3.10. fixed code in [src/pycryptopp/_pycryptoppmodule.cpp](https://github.com/tahoe-lafs/pycryptopp/blob/master/src/pycryptopp/_pycryptoppmodule.cpp): `static PyMethodDef _pycryptopp_functions[] = { {"rsa_generate", reinterpret_cast<PyCFunction>(rsa_generate), METH_KEYWORDS | METH_VARARGS, const_cast<char*>(rsa_generate__doc__)}, /* ... */ };`. python docs: [METH_KEYWORDS](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.METH_KEYWORDS)

Answer (score 0):

`Parser_read` should be

```
static PyObject* Parser_read(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
```

Comment: Not true, he's using the keyword form.