# Obtaining SystemError: Bad call flags in PyCFunction_Call. METH_OLDARGS is no longer supported! while reading a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The Python version which i am using is 3.6.8

While reading training_variants.csv file i am obtaining the below error:
Running the below 2 lines in jupyter notebook.

```
    data = pd.read_csv('training_variants.csv')
    print('Shape of Data: ', data.shape)    

SystemError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-c9e6c2000658> in <module> 
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv('training_variants.csv')
      2 print('Shape of Data: ', data.shape)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700 
    701 read_table = _make_parser_function("read_table", default_sep="\t")
--> 702 read_table = Appender(
    703     _doc_read_csv_and_table.format(
    704         func_name="read_table",

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    427     encoding = kwds.get("encoding", None)
    428     if encoding is not None:
--> 429         encoding = re.sub("_", "-", encoding).lower()
    430         kwds["encoding"] = encoding
    431 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1120         result["na_values"] = na_values
   1121         result["na_fvalues"] = na_fvalues
-> 1122         result["skiprows"] = skiprows
   1123 
   1124         return result, engine

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1832                 values = astype_nansafe(values, str)
   1833 
-> 1834             cats = Index(values).unique().dropna()
   1835             values = Categorical._from_inferred_categories(
   1836                 cats, cats.get_indexer(values), cast_type, true_values=self.true_values

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, kwds)
   1361 
   1362     return parse_dates
-> 1363 
   1364 
   1365 class ParserBase:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _validate_parse_dates_arg(parse_dates)
   1338         return usecols, usecols_dtype
   1339     return usecols, None
-> 1340 
   1341 
   1342 def _validate_parse_dates_arg(parse_dates):

SystemError: Bad call flags in PyCFunction_Call. METH_OLDARGS is no longer supported!
```

Can anyone kindly assist me with what could be the possible reason for this to occur ?

Comment: You should always provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about your question.

Comment: good starting point is to share your pandas version

Comment: @Yuca - the pandas version is 0.24.2.

Comment: By updating the version of pandas using "conda update pandas" command on the terminal as resolved the issue.

Comment: see also [Python C Extension Keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857522/python-c-extension-keyword-arguments) with error `SystemError: Bad call flags in PyCFunction_Call. METH_OLDARGS is no longer supported!`